# python when to encode and when to decode?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

I am always confused when i am supposed to encode or when i am to decode.

What i have understood is, when reading text which in encoded in utf8 i have to Decode. (So when read -> decode)

And when i write i need to encode it in utf8. (So when write -> encode)

But i stumbled upon a weird scenario.

I have a list of stopwords:

```
st = ['la', 'le', ...]
```

I need to filter out list of tuples which include any of these stop words.

To test the filter method i did the following:

```
t = [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c')]  # list of tuples 
st = ['b']  # list of stopwords

# print all tuples which are not in st
print [tup for tup in t if any(i not in tup for i in st)]  

output:  [(1, 'a'), (1, 'c')]
```

So that work.

Now when i put this in implementation i don't get the same result.

list of stopwords:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
stop_words = {
        'fr':
            [
                'au', 'aux', 'avec', 'ce', 'ces',
                'le', 'la'
            ]
```

tuple to filter through:

```
 [(0.11363636363636366, u'arch'), (0.09090909090909093, u's'), (0.06818181818181819, u'la'), (0.04545454545454546, u'av'), (0.04545454545454546, u'champs'), (0.04545454545454546, u'de'), (0.04545454545454546, u'des'), (0.04545454545454546, u'grande'), (0.04545454545454546, u'ground'), (0.04545454545454546, u'm')]
```

filtered tuple

```
[(0.11363636363636366, u'arch'), (0.09090909090909093, u's'), (0.06818181818181819, u'la'), (0.04545454545454546, u'av'), (0.04545454545454546, u'champs'), (0.04545454545454546, u'de'), (0.04545454545454546, u'des'), (0.04545454545454546, u'grande'), (0.04545454545454546, u'ground'), (0.04545454545454546, u'm')]
```

I still have:  u'la'   !

So to test if u'la' in in my stopword list i did the following:

```
[st for st in rs.stop_words['fr'] if st is 'la']
output: ['la']
```

But if i do:

```
[st for st in rs.stop_words['fr'] if st is u'la']
output: []
```

DAMN!

I tried the following but with no success:

```
[st for st in rs.stop_words['fr'] if st is u'la'.encode('utf8')]
output: []

[st for st in rs.stop_words['fr'] if st is u'la'.decode('utf8')]
output: []
```

So now i am stuck with a list of unfiltered tuples.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I haven't understood all of this, but you should definitely not be using `is` to compare strings. `if st == 'la'` should work fine.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you are freaking right! Thanks MAN!

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: @quamrana I am using python 2.7.10

Comment: @PM2Ring Brilliant article. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is really a red herring.  The problem is unrelated to encoding and decoding; instead, the issue is that you are comparing two different types.  A byte string `is` never equivalent to a Unicode string with the same contents.

What you can do instead (but see below) is use `==` instead:

```
>>> u'la' == 'la'
True
```

Even type coercion doesn't help to pass `is` equivalence:

```
>>> u'la' is unicode('la')
False
```

... because `is` compares for identity, not content.

```
>>> '{0} {1}'.format(id(u'la'), id(unicode('la')))
'4458408432 4458408480'
```

4458408432 is not 4458408480, so `is` is not true.

(If you did `id(u'la')` followed by `id(unicode('la'))` you could misleadingly get the same `id` twice, because the first one was rapidly garbage collected, and then its `id` got reused.  Happened to me while writing this.  Putting them both in the same statement demonstrates how they are in fact different.)

The differences between Unicode strings and byte strings *as well as* the functions encoding and decoding are very well explained in Ned Bachtelder's [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) presentation.  The basic recommendation to decode anything as soon as you read it, and encode it only when you need to output it, is very useful advice.  Use Unicode strings throughout your code (except when you really need your bytes to be bytes, not characters, of course) and you will not have unpleasant surprises.

```
# Note the u' prefix throughout!
st = [u'au', u'aux', u'avec', u'ce', u'ces', u'le', u'la']
```

Of course, in Python 3, the `u'` prefix is redundant, because Unicode strings are the default.  But for Python 2, or code which needs to work on both platforms (or just needs to be clear about the string type), always use `u'` for character strings.